# FrameLayout in LinearLayout is pushed to side in View

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, imagebutton, android-framelayout

I have a game layout in my app that has four buttons that should display at the top of my view and then I have two FrameLayouts that are also in this linear layout. The first FrameLayout just makes the top 1/4 of the view so my imageButtons that implement the Drag and drop API are not allowed at the top. The second FrameLayout is for the bottom 3/4 of the view which has 4 imagebuttons in it.

My issue is that when the game layout is displayed, the buttons in the linear layout are displayed just how i want them to, but the two FrameLayouts are squished to the top right corner.

Here is the code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/game_layout" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/doneButton"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onDoneClicked"
            android:text="@string/done" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onCancelClicked"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leaveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onLeaveClicked"
            android:text="@string/leave" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/finishButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onFinishClicked"
            android:text="@string/finish" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/topHalf" >

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/bottomHalf" >

            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/polarCapButton1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                android:background="@drawable/polarcap" />

            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/polarCapButton2"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:background="@drawable/polarcap" />

        </FrameLayout>  


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scores"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/spaceRockButton1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:background="@drawable/spacerock" />

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/spaceRockButton2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:background="@drawable/spacerock" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several things that can be a potential problem.

1. Your linear layout contains several widgets and only 2 of those contain layout_weight values.  To solve this issue, you want to wrap your two frame layouts in another LinerLayout container, where you specify the distribution of your 2 frame layouts inside your new linear layout.
2. In your new linerLayout, you want to specify the total weight of the layout, such as: android:weightSum="1".
3. Depending of your linear layout orientation, (if unspecified, it will be horizontal) If your LinearLayout orientation is horizontal, specify: android:layout_width="0dp". If the orientation is vertical, specify: android:layout_height="0dp" for the child elements.

Also, it seems to me that you want your buttons to align horizontally next to each other (horizontal orientation), and your two frames to align underneath the buttons, but right underneath each other (vertical orientation).

So in this case, the code would look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/top_layout" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/game_layout" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onCancelClicked"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leaveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onLeaveClicked"
            android:text="@string/leave" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/finishButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onFinishClicked"
            android:text="@string/finish" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/ll_layout_frames" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/topHalf" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/bottomHalf" >

            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/polarCapButton1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                android:background="@drawable/polarcap" />

            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/polarCapButton2"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:background="@drawable/polarcap" />

          </FrameLayout> 

      </LinearLayout> 

    <!-- you can insert more widgets here, they will be placed in the vertical linear layout -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See that's similar to how I originally had it and it still aligned the buttons at the top, which I want, but then ththyroid frame layouts would get squished to the right side. I tried it again and it is still doing this.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I made a mistake originally. Please see my updated code. I created an outer linear layout that is vertical, and closed the horizontal orientation linear layout tag that contain your buttons on top. Then, opened a new linear layout container with the weight attributes, which will now align bellow the buttons, not pushed to the side.

Comment: @saboehnke Let me know if this solution worked for you. If it did, please accept my answer. Otherwise, please indicate if you need further help with this.

Comment: I gave that a shot also and the buttons are the only things that are visible now.

Comment: @saboehnke ok, change the layout_height from "match_parent" to "wrap_content" in the linear layout which contains your top navigation buttons. I modified this in my answer as well. It's hard to test your code without the drawables you have, but that should do it.

Comment: "wrap content" means that the container width or height will match the current widget width/height you are wrapping (no additional padding), "match parent" means that it stretches to the width/heigh of your parent container. So knowing this, you will want to play around with the layout_width and layout_height in order to align all your elements exactly how to you want them to look. Alternatively, if in the future you want more freedom in layouting, you could use relative layout.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a screenshot of a sketch of how you want it to look like, or a more detailed description as the second best option.

Comment: I understand all of that. I have tried using wrap_content with the linear layout containing the top buttons but I still just get everything squished to the right side. I have added a screenshot of what I am currently getting. The buttons are fine. I just need everything else to move down and spread out over the screen but no matter what I change it will stay squished.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67741/discussion-between-marta-and-saboehnke).